# Finding number of elements common in two set of permutation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

How to find the number of common terms in two sets of permutation?

I need to find the number of 4-letter words that can be formed out of the letters {a,b,c,d} with the conditions,

1. Letter 'b' appear before c and d

Total number of words from letters {a,b,c,d} = 4! = 24

**Let {A} - set A containing words where 'b' appear before 'c'(but 'b' may or may not appear before 'd')**

 {A} =  {abcd,abdc,adbc,bcda,bcad,bdca,bdac,badc,bacd,dabc,dbca,dbac} = 4!/2! = 12

**Let {B} - set B containing words where 'b' appear before 'd'(but 'b' may or may not appear before 'c')**

 {B} =  {abcd,abdc,acbd,bcda,bcad,bdca,bdac,badc,bacd,cabd,cbad,cbda} = 4!/2! = 12

I need to find out the total number of words which appear in both set A and B. That is, **the words in which b appear both before c and d.** 

 A intersect B = {abcd,abdc,bcda,bcad,bdca,bdac,badc,bacd} = 8

 How to find the number of words in A intersect B ?

Comment: You seem to be describing not "words which appear in both set A and B", but "words which appear in either set A or B". The number of words that appear in _both_ sets should be $0$, because $b$ cannot be followed by $c$ and $d$ simultaneously.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Note that the OP does not want that $b$ is followed *directly* by $c$ and $d$, but that $b$ appears before $c$ and $d$ have appereared, that is, both $c$ and $d$ come *after* $b$.

Comment: Re-framed the question and highlighted the modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is a direct way to compute the interesction, but the following works: A word, where both $c$ and $d$ appear after $b$ must start with either $ab$ or $b$, let's count both groups:

- We have $2! = 2$ words starting with $ab$, as only 2 letters are left to distribute
- We have $3! = 6$ words starting with $b$, as only 3 letters are left to distribute

So alltogether there are $2 + 6 = 8$ words in $A \cap B$.

Comment: In your second case, you meant that there were $3!$ words starting with $\color{red}{b}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig correct

Comment: Thanks for your solution ! Can you extend your solution for more complex cases like the following one. No. of words from letters, {a,b,c,d,e,f,} with the conditions 1. 'a' should appear first, 2. 'b' 'c' should appear after 'a' 3. 'd' 'e' should appear after 'c' 4. 'f' should appear after 'e'. Words with these conditions are {abcdef,abcedf,abcefd,acbdef,acdbef,.......acefdb}= 15 words. In this case, how can I generalize your solution to find out the no. of words which obeys these conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Symmetry lets us handle all these questions.

To answer the original one:  Consider any permutation of your letters.  Within it, $\{b,c,d\}$ occur in some order and all orders are equally likely.  Of the six  possible permutations of $\{b,c,d\}$, $b$ comes first in two.  Hence $b$ is first in a third of the total permutations, so the answer is $$\frac {4!}{3}=8$$

Of course, as $4$ is so small we could simply have enumerated the cases.  They are $$\{bacd,\,badc,\,bcad,\,bdac,\,bcda,\,bdca,\,abcd,\,abdc\}$$

But the symmetry argument works for larger collections.

Counting $A\cap B$ is equivalent to the original question, so the answer is $8$.

Comment: I think the intended question is "In how many permutations of the letters $a, b, c, d$ does $b$ appear before both $c$ and $d$?"

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Is that not what I answered in the first paragraph?  To be clear, I wrote out the explicit enumeration of the cases just to avoid ambiguity as to the meaning of the question.

Comment: It is exactly what you answered before your final paragraph.  I was questioning your final paragraph.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Ah, well perhaps.  The question is poorly phrased.  It refers to "words having letter $b$ followed by $c$ or $d$".  Perhaps "or" meant "and".  Anyway, I figured I'd just answer both.  I'll delete that paragraph if it 's confusing.

Comment: Condition 1 of the question says letter $b$ should be followed by letters $c$ and $d$.  The OP did say what you did in his attempt to answer the question.  You could always add a note before your last paragraph indicating that you can find the number of solutions if letter $b$ is followed by letters $c$ or $d$ in the following manner.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks,  I'll just delete that paragraph.  If the OP wants to reopen that question, I'll take a shot at writing it more clearly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Re-framed the question with clear points.

Comment: @lulu the answer I'm looking for is the number of permutations of **a,b,c,d** in which **b** appear both before **c** and **d**.

Comment: Ok, that's the question that I answered here.

Comment: Thanks for your solution !  Can you extend your solution for more complex cases like the following one. No. of words from letters, {a,b,c,d,e,f,} with the conditions 1. 'a' should appear first, 2. 'b' 'c' should appear after 'a' 3. 'd' 'e' should appear after 'c' 4. 'f' should appear after 'e'. Words with these conditions are {abcdef,abcedf,abcefd,acbdef,acdbef,.......acefdb}= 15 words. In this case, how can I generalize your solution to find out the no. of words which obeys these conditions?

Comment: Those conditions aren't so complex...first just means we are looking at the last $5$ letters (so we start with $5!=120$ permutations).  Second is redundant (follows from first).  third and fourth mean that, of the permutations of $\{c,d,e,f\}$ we want $c$ first (so divide by $4$) and we want $e<f$, (so divide by $2$).  Thus $\frac {120!}{4\times 2}=15$.

Comment: @lulu Awesome !!! Thanks for the solution. Can I generalize the solution: **(No. of words to be arranged) ! / (product of no. of letters to be succeeded after each letter including the letter itself)** In the above case, No. of words to be arranged = 5, No. of letter to succeed letter b = 0; letter c=3; letter d=0; letter e=1; So that the solution could be **5!/([0+1]*[3+1]*[0+1]*[1+1]) = 15**

Comment: @DiNeSH Well, sure.  I'm not saying all sets of conditions can be treated this way...I haven't thought about "all sets of conditions".  but I think the method is very general.